# Constructing vector based on values in dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
 df <- data.frame(Start = c(1,11,26), End = c(10,25,30), Mean = c(0.04349, 0.12, 0.04)) 

 #df
 #  start End    Mean
 #1     1  10 0.04349
 #2    11  25 0.12000
 #3    26  30 0.04000
```

From this, I would like to construct a vector, of which entries would be `Mean`, and indexes are determined by `start` and `end`.

In other words, the vector would have `0.04349` as an entry from index 1 to index 10, then the value of the vector entries would be `0.12` from index 11 to 25, etc.. This is the expected result:

```
 > res = c(rep(0.04349, df$End[1] - df$Start[1] + 1), rep(0.12, df$End[2] - df$Start[2] + 1), rep(0.04, df$End[3] - df$Start[3] + 1))


 > res
  [1] 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.04349 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000
 [19] 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.12000 0.04000 0.04000 0.04000 0.04000 0.04000
```

But the way I am obtaining it above is very inefficient, especially for large number of rows.

Is there a straightforward way of constructing this vector without any for loops? In reality, the dataframe has a large number of rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your updated post you are almost there:

```
with(df, rep(Mean, times=End-start+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[,list(someindex = start:End), by = Mean]
```